# Wordpress Rest Api post fetching

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to show all my posts from my wordpress website. Currently there are 2 posts, you can see it in the json file:
[View](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/#http://feederhorgasz.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed%3Ffilter%5Borderby%5D=date&order=asc)

```
export class HomePage {
url: string = ‘http://feederhorgasz.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed?filter[orderby]=date&order=asc1’;
items: any;

constructor(public navParams: NavParams,public navCtrl: NavController, private http:Http) {

console.log('Passed params', navParams.data);
}
ionViewDidEnter() {
this.http.get( this.url )
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(data =>
{
this.items = data;
console.log(“átadott wp api”,data);

    }); 
}
```

However when i am trying to read from the json, it is listing only one object. (i can see it in the log)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're telling Angular to get a single value from the result. `this.items = data;` where `items: any;` is capable of storing one value, you have to define that you're expecting an array of data not just one object. So the simple answer is:

```js
// By adding [] it will be concidered an array
items: any[];
this.http.get(this.url)
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(data: any[] => {
    //Line below will throw error if it not defined as an array
    this.items = data;
    console.log(“átadott wp api”, data);
  });
```

You're style of code can lead you to a messy project; what I meant is that you should not mix `components` and `services` together, as you have now. It is very beneficial keep services out of component as this will reduce the workload if you have to change one of the `http.get` method for instance; down the line. I'll add snippet for what you should ideally have.

> Homepage Component

```js
export class HomePage {

  items: Type[];
  constructor(public navParams: NavParams, public navCtrl: NavController, private posts: HomepageService) {

    console.log('Passed params', navParams.data);
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.post.getPosts().subscribe(data: Type[] => {
        this.items = data;
        console.log(“átadott wp api”, data);
    });
  }
```

> HomepageService

```js
@Injectable()
export class HomepageService {
  url: string = "http://feederhorgasz.000webhostapp.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed?filter[orderby]=date&order=asc1";

    constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getPosts(): Observable < Type[] > {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
      .map(res => res.json() as Type[])
      .catch((err: Response) => Observable.throw(console.log(err)));
  }
```

As you can see, if you want to change the URL of the endpoint, you only need to update single file; not all the component that you've written that service.

> Class (`Type`)

You should also use `classes` to map response JSON so Angular can interact with it as an object, instead of some type of string. [Class](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1)